# Anonymous type and LINQ and casting

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework-5, anonymous

I'm pretty stuck on this anonymous type from LINQ business. It's a consequence of working through an answer to a previous question, but sadly I just havent the brain power to get this to work at all.

I'm returning a limited list of events that are connected to each person. The source is Entity Framework where I'm still battling to get criteria limited results from a navigation property. The code below is my translation from Nicholas Butler's answer. However, I can't find any way to adapt the anonymous type. Casts don't seem to work - or I just haven't a clue (likely). Can anyone help please?

```
Dim test = context.persons.Where(Function (r) r.personActive).Select(Function (o) New With { _
                 .person = o, _
                 .events = o.events.Where( Function(e) e.eventDateTime > startdate) _
            })

            Dim Res = New ObservableCollection(Of person )

            For Each person In test
                Res.Add(person)
            Next
```

Gives me:

> Error     2     Value of type '<anonymous type> (line 53)' cannot be converted to 'PersonEntity.person'.     E:\Dropbox\Work Experimental\PersonEntity- Copy\PersonEntity\personRepository.vb     61     29     PersonEntity

I've gotten further with this code but I still cannot have the attached events as I get yet another error with the casting, this time of events. Generic List to ObservableList doesn't convert apparently. It seems an incredible way round to answer my original question!

```
Dim test = context.persons.Where(Function(r) r.personActive).Select(Function(o) New With { _
                 .person = o, _
                 .events = o.events.Where(Function(e) e.eventDateTime > startdate) _
            })


            Dim Res = New ObservableCollection(Of person)

            For Each t In test
                Dim r As New person
                r = t.person
                r.events = t.events
                Res.Add(r)
            Next

            Return Res
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Function(o) New With { _
         .person = o, _
         .events = o.events.Where(Function(e) e.eventDateTime > startdate) _
    }
```

This returns an anonymous type, not a `Person`. Did you mean to `Add` its `person` property*?

```
For Each o In test
    Res.Add(o.person)
Next
```

Comment: This was part of another problem, which I've just managed to resolve in another question. Thank you. And your right :) That's exactly what I had to do.